# Echo a TIMESTAMP value taken from a database and display with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, timestamp

I am querying a database to retrieve the time that an item was entered. This item is a TIMESTAMP. I am echoing it from php back to my main page. When displaying the time in an html table, it displays properly (i.e. YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:MS) However, when I click on the button to check the value with jQuery, the page only alerts YYYY-MM-DD). JS's Date() function does not seem to be appropriate here, as it returns the current time. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Expected alert: 2013-11-20 02:04:43
Actual alert: 2013-11-20

page1.php:

```
$('.content').on('click', '.remove_button', function(){
var clicked = $(this);
alert((clicked.val()));
});
```

page2.php:

```
$findMsg = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT (m.timeSent)AS time FROM MessageAdmin m");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($findMsg)){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['time']."</td>";
    echo "<td><button class='remove_button' value=".$row['time'].">Delete</button></td>";
    echo "</tr>";       
}
```

Comment: I would like to point out that the Date object will return any date you put into it: `new Date('04/06/1992 12:31:12')`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need quotes around the timestamp in the `value` attribute, otherwise the space after the date terminates the value:

```
    echo "<td><button class='remove_button' value='".$row['time']."'>Delete</button></td>";
```